# Shell command in .m file?

Tags: objective-c, system

I tried using system() to run a shell command in a .m file, but to no avail. How is it possible to run a shell command from a .m file in Xcode?

```
#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [output setStringValue:@"Awaiting orders, sir."];
}

- (IBAction)convertFile:(id)sender
{
    NSString *string = [input stringValue];
    NSString *string2 = @"tar czvf ProjectFiles.tar.gz ";



    NSString *stringCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", string2, string];

    system(stringCmd);
}
@end
```

Comment: It is. How were you using it?

Comment: `system()` works. Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

NSTask is an alternative. Check out the [NSTask Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So - (void)setLaunchPath:(NSString *)path?

Comment: NSTask is a good alternative to system indeed. For usage examples, you can search NSTask on stackoverflow, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211737/nstask-question

Answer (score 0):

Your code failed because *system* expects a C string (*char **) and your stringCmd is a *NSString **.

Try using:

```
system([stringCmd cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Also note that *system* runs the command in a shell so be aware for potential security problems.
If your input string is *@"tt.txt; echo \"aa\""* your code will run

```
tar czvf ProjectFiles.tar.gz tt.txt; echo "aa"
```

This may or not be what you intend.

Comment: echo "aa" is just an example. It could just as well be "rm -rf /" or some other destructive command.